# How to select specific data in dynamic table using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to automate some scenarios using protractor where we need to verify whether the data is updating in dynamic table.

Please find below

HTML Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6oon.png)

Table in page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78QNa.png)

Comment: Please show what you have tried when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by verifying that element is present in the DOM with the added Group ID or Group Name.

For Group ID:

> element(by.xpath("*//table//tbody//tr//td[1]//p[text()='Amanda Test
>   Group']")).isDisplayed()

For Group name:

> element(by.xpath("*//table//tbody//tr//td[2]//p[text()='Amanda
>   Group']")).isDisplayed()

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Angular2+, yes?

In your HTML Template, you are probably using an `*ngFor` directive to populate the table dynamically. Add an index to the `*ngFor` (it's best practices for updating the DOM) in order to add a dynamic id to each element:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let user of user; index as u" id="user-{{u + 1}}">
        <td id="userName-{{u + 1}}">
            {{user.firstName}} {{user.userName}}<br />
            {{user.userName}}
        </td>
        <td id="userRoles-{{ u + 1 }}">
            <span id="role-{{u + 1}}-{{ r + 1 }}" *ngFor="let role of user.roles; index as r">
                {{ role.toUpperCase() + ', '}}
            </span>
        </td>
        <!- Omitted code -->
    </tr>
```

In your Page Object:

```js
// Get first user on the table
get firstUser() {
    return element(by.id('user-1');
}

// Get a specific user by id
public getUser(index: number) {
    return element(by.id(`user-${index}`);
}

// Get all of the attributes for a single user by id
get userAttributes(index: number) {
    return element.all(by.id(`user-${index}`);
}
```

I am not a fan of `xpath` selectors. Yes, they are faster. But in code that is dynamic or changes frequently, they are the most fragile of selectors. There is no reason your dynamic data cannot have a dynamic ID that clearly identifies each portion of the code you need.

Good luck!